# Android layout problem

Tags: android, layout

I am using a header that includes two `TextView`s in the center and to the left of the `TextView` I am having two `Button`s and to right of the `TextView` I am having two `Button`s. All these four `Button`'s visibility is set to `gone`.

> Button 1 (gone) -- Button
>   2 (gone) -- Textview 1 -- TextView
>   2 -- Button 3 (gone) -- Button4 (gone)

The problem is that if I make only `Button 1` visible the `TextView` appears in the center if I make only `Button 2` visible my `TextView` moves closer to `Button 2`.

What I want is that my `TextView' is always centerd.

How can I do that?

My code is:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/back"
    android:background="@drawable/back" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
<Button android:id="@+id/allcities"
    android:background="@drawable/campusbttn"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/quaddeal_header_text"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Quad"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/green" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/allcities" />    

<TextView android:id="@+id/quaddeal_header_text_add"
    android:layout_width="50dip" 
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Deals"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quaddeal_header_text" />  

<Button android:id="@+id/quad_share"
    android:background="@drawable/share"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<Button android:id="@+id/quad_login"
    android:background="@drawable/button_img"
    android:text="Login"     
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the `Button`'s visibility to `gone` but to `invisible`. If you set the visibility to `gone`then the entire space that `View` would take up is gone which in your case moves your other `View`s around.

However you should rethink your layout a bit.